# How to create an account in a Dapp which developed with Parity

Tags: dapp-development, parity, accounts, dapp-design

I’m developing a Dapp about image storing with Parity these days. And I try to make a new account with JSONRPC right now. But when I searched for some useful API, I found an API in this web:[parity_newAccountFromSecret](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity_accounts-module#parity_newaccountfromsecret)

In this API parity_newAccountFromSecret, it says creates a new account from a **private ethstore secret key**. But how and where to get it?

And there are some APIs about account, such as parity_accounts, [personal_accounts](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-personal-module), I don't know their differences clearly. Can you give me some advice? Thanks a lot~ :)

Comment: Your alternatives are `personal_newAccount` or `parity_newAccountFromPhrase`.